# Hibernate in kotlin fails a simple integration test (persist followed by remove)

Tags: hibernate, kotlin

I created a test, that tests whether removing just created entity truly removes the record from the DB. The **entity** `BigClass` looks like this:

```
@Entity
class BigClass(@Column(nullable = false)
               val name: String,

               @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL]) 
               val map: Set<MapEntry>) : PanacheEntity



@Entity
class MapEntry(@OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
               val keyList: Keys,

               @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL]) 
               val valueList: Values) : PanacheEntity


@Entity
class Keys(@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
           val list: Set<Key>) : PanacheEntity


@Entity
class Values(@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
             val list: Set<Value>) : PanacheEntity


@Entity
class Key(@Column(nullable = false) 
          val name: String,

          @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
          val ids: Set<String>) : PanacheEntity


@Entity
class Value(@Column(nullable = false) 
            val name: String,

            @Column(nullable = false) 
            val description: String) : PanacheEntity
```

and this is the **test**

```
@BeforeAll
fun setup() {
    val ef = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test")
    sessionFactory = ef.unwrap(SessionFactory::class.java)
}    


suspend fun create(entity: BigClass): String {
    sessionFactory.withTransaction { s ->
            s.persist(entity)
        }.awaitSuspending()
        return entity.id.toString()
}


suspend fun delete(id: String) {
        sessionFactory.withTransaction { s ->
            s.find(BigClass::class.java, id.toLong())
            .map { s.remove(it) }
        }.awaitSuspending()
}

suspend fun read(id: String): BigClass? {
    return sessionFactory.withTransaction { s ->
        s.find(BigClass::class.java, id.toLong())
     }.awaitSuspending()
} 



@Test
fun createAndDelete() {
    runBlocking {
        val id = create(testEntity)
        delete(id)

        val actual = read(id)

        assertEquals(null, actual)   // actually is still testEntity
    }
}
```

This straightforward test, however, fails, as the `actual` is still the allegedly removed entity. Any thoughts why?

Answer (score 0):

what if flush before read?

```
     val id = create(testEntity)
        delete(id)
entityManager.flush()
        val actual = read(id)
```

Comment: I tried to flush it within withTransaction context, didn't work. Isn't different if I have an entityManager? How to I get one from sessionFactory?

Comment: Also if I only create and delete the record straight after the record is not deleted, as I can check the table in the database.